OYin Yang logo with the warped γ inside
I'm trying to learn the process of warping an image the way Guy Steele did in the so-called Yin and Langda logo in the year of 1989.

Here is what I managed to do so far.

On Adobe Illustrator CS5(see note below), I did  "Type on a path tool" >> Glyph, select the Greek letter "Gamma"
Vectorize the letter by Command + Shift + O
Enlarge it. Warp is using some options which I don't remember at the moment.
Notice that in my amateurish work the thickness of the Gamma letter is not preserved uniformly.
I've tried the envelope tool with various options such as skew, flag, etc I still couldn't replicate the warped γ in the Steele's logo.
How to go about it so that the warped γ looks like as in the Steele's logo (i.e. not like my amateurish work) ?
The answer is expected to list all the steps required to get the Steele's γ. I'm interested in the process of doing it as much as the end result of it.
It would be nice if the answer could be applied to some other letters such as pi (Π), sigma (Σ), etc too.
Note: Any program other than Adobe Illustrator can be used. AI is not the only vector graphics program out there.

First, different fonts have different widths for strokes and some fonts do not use a uniform width. So you first need to choose a font that has a uniform width for all strokes. But then the strokes at different positions in the letter will react to the distortion tools differently, resulting in not so uniform thickness. In the end, it'll be musch easier to just draw the shape you need.

@Betty I've edited the last section of the question. Applicability of the process to other fonts or letters is only optional  Being able to produce a warped γ from scratch in Steele's style is enough for me :) May I kindly remind that Steele managed to get that perfectly warped γ shape using whatever application was available in 1989?

Regarding the "end of the question" -- I'm not sure a full tutorial on "how to draw" is appropriate. That's not really "help" that's instruction. There are hours of YouTube videos regarding how to draw using Illustrator. In addition to Adobe's own teaching materials. Then there are school, courses, and online educational outlets. It's not the goal of Stack Exchange to teach software usage, but rather to help if you get stuck. In short.. asking for someone to explain the steps of drawing is a bit extreme.

@Scott Well, if no one can help with the question here for a week or two I 'll try to reach Guy Steele and ask how he did that warped γ. If he shows how he did it, I will post it as the answer. I've just edited the question. Any program other than Adobe Illustrator can be used. AI isn't the sole vector graphics application out there.

Just want to point out that that is a lambda, not a Y. The logo is for Lisp which is a programming language that has anonymous functions called lambdas. They borrowed that term from lambda calculus. It might actually be "used straight out of the box" but if not, I suspect that this was created originally as a raster image using a bulge filter (i.e. lens/pinch effect) which was then plopped on top of a yin-yang. It is a little amateurish.

Not asked, but the mentioned person Guy Steele very likely had something more sophisticated things to do than bending letters. Not claiming that he had no effect to the formation of the shown logo, but the person could understand the logic foundations BEHIND mathematics and worked with software implementations which could proceed calculations in such formal logic. The distorted gamma is very likely not gamma at all, but letter lambda turned upside down. I believe it's taken from the works of Alonzo Church who was one of the 20th century pioneers who succeeded in building a formal logic system which theoretically can describe everything (including mathematics) which can be described and rendered by using formal languages and algorithms. Of course, not everyone can actually understand properly such creations, but anyone (including me) can pick from Wikipedia the name of Church's theoretical logic machine. It's "Lambda Calculus".
At the 2nd half of 1980's vector graphics programs were already available, so it was no problem to draw your distorted letter. Mr.Kerr has already shown roughly one way and I can show another which uses Inkscape.
Click with the pen tool on your screenshot to make a closed polygon which has the minimum number (=8) of nodes to make the shape possible:

Push and pull the curve with the node tool to change straight segments to curved. No need to edit the nodes nor node handles. except it's useful to select the middle node on the curved section and set its type to "symmetric" to get easily regular look. With few pushes and pulls you get this:

It's also useful to align the 4 top line nodes and the 2 bottom line nodes to same elevations with Align & Distribute panel.
If you can accept the obvious nearly 1 px error you get even more regular look by deleting the middle node and readjusting the curve. I would accept it just for the easily increased regularity:

In the next image the shape is duplicated. The green stroke is removed and black fill color is inserted.
It doesn't become better than this without having a sharper image as the starting point or other knowledge of the actual wanted form.

The problem is that the γ is nothing like the letter in the original.
Rather than trying to modify an existing letter, you could instead use the bitmap image and trace the letter over the top, using the Pen Tool.


Yup.. draw it don't "Set it".

Thank you for the answer. I'd like to know how to warp any letter, which happens to be the letter Gamma γ here, in the same manner as Steele's. Suppose I wanted to fit a warped Rho ρ into the Yin Yang shape. How would I do it?

@LarsMalmsteen To distort a letter you could use Object > Envelope Distort > Make with mesh, but it won't work well with your example as the letter is just too different. You could also edit the anchors and Bézier curves of an existing letter, but it's much more effort than simply redrawing it from scratch.
